# Unable to write the correct XML data from CLOB column

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

/* I have written the below procedure which writes the CLOB column data to the physical location in the XML format. The file gets successfully written but getting truncated or missing the correct XML format.*/

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_generate_xml
IS

  c_amount         BINARY_INTEGER := 32767;
  l_buffer         VARCHAR2(32767);
  l_chr10          PLS_INTEGER;
  l_clobLen        PLS_INTEGER;
  l_fHandler       UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  l_pos            PLS_INTEGER    := 1;
 l_clob           CLOB;
 l_message_num number;
 l_cnt number;
 l_err_msg varchar2(3000);
 v_sysdate date;

BEGIN

l_message_num := 1;

   for c2 in ( SELECT xml_clob , case_id FROM AUDIT_XML_CLOB where case_id = '2006S1000018') 
   loop

   select  count(1) into l_cnt from AUDIT_XML_CLOB where nvl(DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(xml_clob),0) > 0;

    if l_cnt > 0 then 

      l_pos := 1;

       SELECT xml_clob
        INTO  l_clob 
        FROM AUDIT_XML_CLOB where case_id = c2.case_id;

          l_fHandler := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('MY_DIR1', 'test.xml','W',c_amount);

l_clobLen  := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(l_clob);                             


             WHILE l_pos < l_clobLen
              LOOP

                l_buffer := DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(l_clob, c_amount, l_pos);    

                EXIT WHEN l_buffer IS NULL;

 UTL_FILE.PUT_line(l_fHandler, l_buffer,TRUE);
                l_pos := l_pos + LEAST(LENGTH(l_buffer)+1,c_amount);
                dbms_output.put_line('l_pos:'||l_pos);  

UTL_FILE.FFLUSH (l_fHandler); 

END LOOP;

  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(l_fHandler);

l_message_num := l_message_num +1;

end if;
    end loop;
commit;
dbms_output.put_line('4');
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  IF UTL_FILE.IS_OPEN(l_fHandler) THEN
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(l_fHandler);
  END IF;
  --RAISE;
l_err_msg:= substr(sqlerrm,1,3000);

dbms_output.put_line(l_err_msg);

END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Fast way to dump clob to new file is use DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.clob2file(...) 
2) What is wrong with your xml?

```
begin 
   for c2 in ( SELECT xml_clob , case_id FROM AUDIT_XML_CLOB where case_id = '2006S1000018') 
   loop
      dbms_xslprocessor.clob2file(CL=> c2.xml_clob, FLOCATION=>'MY_DIR1', FNAME=>'test.xml', CSID=>0);
   end loop;
end;
```

Where MY_DIR1 exists and you have privilege to write in this location.

Comment: Some of the tags got omitted in the downloaded XML file

Comment: Can you please let me know how to use dbms_xlsprocessor.clob2file in the above code?